# How can I add/manage persistent URL parameters for Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, anchor

Say I have two resource lists on my site: users and groups. When I am paging through each in increments of 10, I want to save the state of my list such that when I give the URL of the page to someone, they will be navigated to the same page with the same page size.

This is easy with one list, and I would even forgo the Ajax and use simple HTTP parameters, but to add to the complexity, the Ajax commands both take the same parameters, for instance:

```
user/getlist?maximum=10&offset=0&systemId=123456
group/getlist?maximum=10&offset=0&systemId=123456
```

Originally, I was thinking of using anchors, so that the URL would look like:

```
admin/users+groups.php#?maximum=10&offset=0&systemId=123456
```

But this obviously would not work with two lists. Can I do this easy in jQuery, or would I need to code this in raw JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure if i completely understand your question - but, since your end goal is to have a link, AJAX is actually off the table... why not stick with your original plan, but do something simple like add a param for which list you are trying to modify, like so: `admin/users-groups.php?view=users&max[...]` -?

Comment: I'm coding off an existing system and I can't change the fact that these are Ajax calls.

Comment: Then what is the problem? As long as you have two controls - one for one list, and one for the other, I don't see any issues arising from what you're describing...

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't specific enough in my question. Is there a quick way to do this (or something like it) in jQuery or would I have to code a bunch of `.substring` lines until it works? I think I can use jQuery.param to create the parameter list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. First, we need to load the AJAX parameters from the anchor on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#?') == 0) {
        var hashParameters = window.location.hash.substring(2).split('&');
        var hashIndex = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < hashParameters.length; i++) {
            var hp = hashParameters[i]
            var delim = hp.indexOf('=');
            var key = hp.substring(0, delim);
            var value = hp.substring(delim + 1);

            addParameter();
            $('#parameter-' + i + '-key').val(key);
            $('#parameter-' + i + '-value').val(value);
        }
    } else {
        addParameter();
        $('#parameter-0-key').val('id');
    }
});
```

`addParameter()` is a method that adds the AJAX parameters to the page visually, and then I am updating its values.

Then it's just a matter of building up the anchor and setting it back to the URL:

```
function getParameterValues() {
    // ...
    var anchor = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
        var keyName = '#parameter-' + i + '-key';
        var valueName = '#parameter-' + i + '-value'; 
        var key = $(keyName).val();
        var value = $(valueName).val();
        if (typeof key == 'undefined' || typeof value == 'undefined') {
            continue;
        }

        if (key == '') {
            continue;
        }

        // ...

        if (anchor.length == 0) {
            anchor += '?' + key + '=' + value;
        } else {
            anchor += '&' + key + '=' + value;
        }
    }
    window.location.hash = '#' + anchor;
    return values;
}
```

It would be nice if jQuery ever came up with a way to add/remove parameters to the URL like this itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a comma (or dash) separator, and make each of your lists a querystring parameter.

Update, the URL of the page looks like this:
    admin/users+groups.php?ulist=10,0,123456&glist=12,0,123457

Then in javascript, call this function to get querystring parameter values:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

// you should probably break this out and null check the parameter before splitting, but for the sake of brevity:
var userListVals=getParameterByName("ulist").split(","); 
var groupListVals=getParameterByName("glist").split(","); 

var userListURL = "/user/getlist?maximum=" + userListVals[0] + "&offset=" + userListVals[1] + "@systemId=" + userListVals[2];
var groupListURL = "/user/getlist?maximum=" + groupListVals[0] + "&offset=" + groupListVals[1] + "@systemId=" + groupListVals[2];
```

It relies on the values being in the proper order, but if you're generating the URLs yourself, that shouldn't be a problem.

Update:

Comment: But I'm querying two unique resources, `user` and `group`. I can't combine listings together like this.

Comment: Check out the changes.  I think this will get you all of the parameters you want in the URL, and then break them into something useful for each list ajax request.

Comment: It doesn't work because every time I try to go forward a page, the Ajax will update the URL and actually navigate to a new page, i.e. `?ulist=10,0,123456&glist=12,0,123457` `?ulist=10,10,123456&glist=12,0,123457` causes a new page to load.

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  Can you post the whole ajax call code?  The ajax call shouldn't be changing your page URL.  It should only be taking the values from the URL and passing them into a web service call behind the scenes.  Then of course, after the initial page load, it should rely on some variables that you're keeping the current page in, instead of the querystring values.

Comment: But that's exactly what I need to do. I _need_ the AJAX call to change the URL so that the client can copy the page's URL to us for support or to other members of the client's organization.